# Rewriting simple iTextSharp read page function using iText7 library

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I've been using the iTextSharp library in my C# .NET program to read PDF files. A simplified version of my program uses code like the following procedure to get the text for a specified page number in a PDF File.

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System.Text;

namespace PDFReaderITextSharp
{
    public static class PdfHelper
    {
        public static string GetText(string fileName, int pageNumber)
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, pageNumber, strategy);
            currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
            return currentText;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to construct a similar type of function that does that same thing but using the iText7 library in a .NET Core 3 program, namely, return the text for a specified PDF page. However, when I look at the text that is returned and compare it to the text returned by the above function as well as visually looking at the PDF file using an Adobe Reader, I see document text being represented multiple times.

For example, when I look at the PDF file in Adobe, there are several fields displayed in the form of "Caption: Value". For example, Invoice #: 1234 Invoice Date: 12/32/2019. But the text returned using the iText7 library returns "Invoice#Invoice #: 1234 Invoice DateInvoice Date: 12/32/2019" (the labels are duplicated 2 or more times.)

I wish I could upload the PDF document to help.

Is there something wrong with the iText7 function? What might the iText7 library be doing?

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener;

namespace PDFReader.Helpers
{
    public static class PdfHelperIText7
    {
        public static string GetPdfPageText(string pdfFilePath, int pageNumber)
        {
            using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfFilePath)))
            {
                FilteredEventListener listener = new FilteredEventListener();
                LocationTextExtractionStrategy extractionStrategy = listener.AttachEventListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
                PdfCanvasProcessor pdfCanvasProcessor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(listener);
                listener.AttachEventListener(extractionStrategy);
                pdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessPageContent(pdfDocument.GetPage(pageNumber));
                string actualText = extractionStrategy.GetResultantText();
                pdfDocument.Close();
                return actualText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"the labels are duplicated 2 or more times"* - this usually means that the labels are present in the pdf 2 or more times. Probably drawn at nearly the same position to achieve a poor-man's-bold effect.

Comment: You used `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` in iText 5. It is also present in iText 7, why have you switched to the new strategy?

Comment: I actually tried both Strategies and got the same undesirable result with iText 7.

Comment: My first thought, too, was that the multiple instance of the caption were actually in the file but I don't think so. I don't think so, because I overrode the Strategy classes and intercepted the individual Rectangles that were written to the page and I only saw one occurrence for all of these captions that were duplicated when text for the who page was returned. If I had to guess, I would say that the new library didn't properly keep track of which text rectangle were previously returned and accidentally returned some twice in the text. I'd love to be proved wrong.

Comment: Please share the pdf in question to allow reproducing the issue.

Comment: I would like to but my company policy prohibits and prevents me from doing that